# Access dollar sign in parameters in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dollar-sign

I am working in Asp.Net Core Web API. I write a GET API. In API, the input parameters have come with the `$` symbol from the URL. But in c#, if parameter come with dollar symbol means, not able to access. How to take the input values if parameters have a `$` symbol in front of the parameter name?

```
 public class DataProperties
 {
    [JsonProperty("skip")]
    public int Skip { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("top")]
    public int Top { get; set; }
 }
```

***Controller***

```
 [HttpGet("list")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ListAsync([FromQuery]DataProperties data)
{
}
```

***URL Format***

`/api/v1/list?$Skip=10&$Top=10`

It works fine when giving without `$` symbol like

`/api/v1/tickets/list?Skip=10&Top=10`

***Note***

I am using `ODataAdaptor`. So when using OData Adaptor, the parameters automatically come with the `$` symbol in front of the parameter name.

Comment: What is the reason for having `$` sign in front of parameter name?

Comment: In short, don't do it. those types of characters cant be part of a part of a URL without encoding

Comment: @Fabio  -  I am using ODataAdaptor. So when using OData Adaptor, the parameters automatically come with the $ symbol in front of the parameter name.

Comment: I haven't implemented oData - Try to Enable `oDataQueryOptions` Instead of parsing your own model   [For Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#enable]

Comment: @user2932057 - In my case, I don't need to use `oDataQueryOptions`. Instead of it, I implemented my own model class.

Comment: @NivithaGopalakrishnan - Then, You internally translate from your model (skip) to oData structure($skip) while querying

Comment: @user2932057 - When giving like `$skip=10` means, the input parameter is taking the value as null instead of 10.

Comment: @NivithaGopalakrishnan - whether you are returning oDataResponse as response from API ?

Comment: Try In Startup.cs - `config.EnableQuerySupport();` And In your controller `Task<ActionResult> ListAsync([FromODataUri]ODataQueryOptions data)`

Comment: @user2932057 - We no need to use ODataQueryOptions. Instead of it, I create my own class.

Comment: @NivithaGopalakrishnan - Just a work around - Try this `[JsonProperty("$skip")]`

Comment: @user2932057 - I tried to like that also `[JsonProperty("$skip")]`

Comment: Make a final try of the snippet - `[FromQuery(Name ="$Skip")]                                                                               
 public int Skip { get; set; }`

Comment: @user2932057 - Thanks. The above solution `[FromQuery(Name ="$Skip")]` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because C# does not allow `$` at the start of a variable name, but this is a valid key for a parameter in a query string, you can decorate your parameters with the `[FromQuery]` attribute, and specify the name explicitly, for example, if implementing the standard OData `$skip` and `$top` parameters:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery(Name = "$top")] string top, [FromQuery(Name = "$skip")] string skip)
{
    // ...
}
```